# How could I add prices of the cars together and make the total write to the text file?

Tags: python

```
def getCars():

    intro()

    amountofDreamCars = int(input('How many dream cars do you have? '))
    print()

    file = open('Dreamcars.txt','w')

    print('Please enter the following information:')
    print()

    for count in range(1, amountofDreamCars + 1):
       
        make = input('Make: ')
        model = input('Model: ')
        year = int(input('Year: '))
        price = input('Price: ')

        
        file.write(str(make) + '\n')
        file.write(str(model) + '\n')
        file.write(str(year) + '\n')
        file.write(str(price) + '\n')
        print()


    file.close()
    print('Your dream cars and the total value of them has been saved to Dreamcars.txt')


def intro():
    print('This program will ask you to enter the make, model and price of the')
    print('dream cars you have. It will then calculate the total price of all the cars')
    print('and write it to a file alongside the user input.')
    print()

getCars()
```

Answer (score 0):

Define a total outside the for loop and add each price to it.

```
def getCars():

    intro()

    amountofDreamCars = int(input('How many dream cars do you have? '))
    print()

    file = open('Dreamcars.txt','w')

    print('Please enter the following information:')
    print()
    total_price = 0
    for count in range(1, amountofDreamCars + 1):
       
        make = input('Make: ')
        model = input('Model: ')
        year = int(input('Year: '))
        price = input('Price: ')
        total_price += int(price)
        
        file.write(str(make) + '\n')
        file.write(str(model) + '\n')
        file.write(str(year) + '\n')
        file.write(str(price) + '\n')
        print()
    file.write("TOTAL" + str(total_price) + '\n')

    file.close()
    print('Your dream cars and the total value of them has been saved to Dreamcars.txt')
```

Comment: I am getting an error that says: total_price += price
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +=: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: Sorry, I corrected that in an edit. I forgot to change price to an int since all input is interpreted as a string